# Accessing JpegEncoder class from JavaScript in Adobe AIR application

Tags: javascript, air

I need to encode a BitmapData object using the JPegEncoder in a Adobe AIR application using JavaScript

I am trying to create a JpegEncoder object

```
var encoder=new window.runtime.mx.graphics.codec.JPEGEncoder()
```

and I get the error

> TypeError: Result of expression
>   'window.runtime.mx.graphics.codec.JPEGEncoder' [] is not a
>   constructor.

I am not sure if I done something wrong or it is not possible to access that class
This is my mxml header

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/2.6">
```

Update:
I found that you need to add a reference to the swf/swc ,here is a smaple code for an application that uses rpc

```
<script type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
src="lib/air/swf/framework/framework/library.swf"></script>
<script type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
src="lib/air/swf/framework/rpc/library.swf"></script>
```

I tried adding mx instead of rpc but it does not work, I am thinking if i need to deploy the mx.swc file with the application?(i think it should not be needed) or maybe it can't resolve that path

I solved it by deploying the framework.swf file wioth the application but can it be done without it?Is this file present on the client machines?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why the 'window.runtime'...

using `xmlns:mx="http://www.adobe.com/2006/mxml"` and explicitly importing the class works fine for me...
And you would also get a compiler warning about not specifying a type for the variable, ie you want:

```
import mx.graphics.codec.JPEGEncoder;

var encoder:JPEGEncoder = new JPEGEncoder();
```

And please - I have seen far to much AS code that relies on not requiring a semi-colon to terminate a statement - use them - the FB ide is much nicer if you do (auto-correct indenting etc), not to mention this often leads to mixed 'usage' with some lines using it other not - I wish adobe would remove this 'feature'

Comment: My code is JavaSCript , my application is an HTMl/AIR application, I wrote the code in AS3 and test it but I need it in JavaScript